# Given any 3 vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \mathbf{R}^3$, we can always find real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3$ not all zero s.t., $\sum a_iv_i=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Given any three vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \mathbf{R}^3$, we can always find real numbers $a_1, a_2, a_3$ not all zero s.t., $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$ = 0

I was looking through an old exam paper and we had to mark this statement as true or false. I marked it as True but can't remember the reasoning behind it, which was incorrect.

Comment: What happen if $v_i$ are independent?

Answer (score 3):

It is false. With $v_1=(1,0,0),v_2=(0,1,0),v_3=(0,0,1)$ then we must have $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$.

Answer (score 1):

this statement is false.

an easy example is the $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

it is also easy to understand why, let's the above 3 vectors be the axis of $\Bbb R^3$ space, so if there is $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$ for which one of the $a'$s is not $0$ then there will be a point on $\Bbb R^3$ which is NOT the origin that will be equal $(0,0,0)$ and this is false. this kind of set of vectors are called Linearly independent vectors and the span of $n$ Linearly independent vectors is the vector space $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: btw the example i gave is called Natural basis vectors of $\Bbb R^3$